# Listado de cubos activos y usuarios conectados a cubos

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito alguna query que me puea devolver que cubos en Analisys Services se encuentran activos y aparte una query que pueda obtener un historial de usuarios y a que cubos se han conectado.

Probe utilizando `select * from $system.discover_sessions` y `select * from $system.discover_connections`, pero no me entregan la informacion que necesito.

Comment: Qué has investigado? Qué has intentado? Por qué las queries no te *entregan la información* que necesitas? Qué palabras utilizaste en google? Ya buscaste en los foros de Microsoft? A qué te refieres con *cubos activos*? Qué tal [Extended Events](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6121/monitoring-sql-server-analysis-services-with-extended-events/)?

Comment: He investigado en google usando `list users access cubes sql server`, ademas de buscar por `listado usuarios acceso a cubos sql server`. La query que me ha servido ha sido `SELECT * FROM $system.mdschema_cubes WHERE CUBE_SOURCE=1`, pero este solo me entrega el listado de cubos. Lo que necesito, es un reporte que me entregue un listado de usuarios que se conecten a los cubos, ya que se debe determinar que cubos estan siendo utilizados y cuales no.

Comment: Ejemplo, `$system.discover_sessions` me entrega los usuarios que se han conectado a Analisys, pero no muestra a que cubos se han conectado, que es el factor que necesito